# ActiveRecord model column not updating (even though save! succeeds)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a really, really odd problem manifesting on a big Rails e-commerce app and thought I'd see if anyone has good insight. I have an"Order" model with many associations. If I create a new instance, and then set one particular column value and "save!" the "save!" is succeeding without errors, but the change isn't actually persisted to the DB. I'll run through the scenario below:

```
@order = Order.create!(<some attributes>)
=> true

@order.shipping_method_id
=> 1

@order.shipping_method_id = 203
=> 203

@order.save!
=> true

@order.shipping_method_id
=> 1
```

To try and debug this I actually prepended a before_save filter and I can see that when this first filter is called after setting the value, it is correct ("203") BUT the very next before_save after the 6-or-so built-in "autosave_foo_bar_quux" filters (for nested associations) it is back to "1".

Oddly, if I just reload the order (@order.reload), change the column value and save! the update does succeed.

In both cases, doing @order.changed shows that ActiveModel recognizes the column value change for shipping_method_id. In the first, though, the SQL logging shows that the order row is not updated.

I feel like I'm going insane. Any ideas? Also, let me know if there's anything else I can post here for more context.

Comment: Would you be able to post the full Order class?

Comment: Somewhere in the associations, a database constraint calling a rollback!